# About man who is kept alive by a cold machine

Tags: story-identification, tv

The story is about a man who meets a woman in his apartment.  The apartment is very cold as are his hands.  There is the constant sound of machinery running the back ground.

So long as the refrigeration equipment runs is stays alive.

During the course of the episode the machine stops.

This was an early sixties show.

Any ideas out there?

Mahalo

Comment: What kind of show? TV?

Comment: Can you remember how the refrigeration equipment was linked to his immortality?

Comment: Sounds like an episode of the original *Outer Limits*, at first glance.

Answer (score 11):

This sounded sufficiently similar to ['Cool Air' by HP Lovecraft](http://www.hplovecraft.com/writings/texts/fiction/ca.aspx) for me to check if it had been adapted for television around the period you identified.  [It has](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cool_Air#Adaptations).

> "Cool Air" has been adapted for [...] television [...] as [a 1971 episode of Night Gallery directed by Jeannot Szwarc
>   with a teleplay by Rod Serling](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0660800/) (where the narrator was changed to the
>   daughter of a MIT colleague of Muñoz's, in order to accommodate a
>   romantic plot for the story).

Could this be it?